# How to make the height of a dynamically-sized <div> the same as the width

Tags: css

I have a div whose width is a percentage of the width of its container. My question is how can I ensure that the height is the same pixel length as the width, given that the container is not a square (so I can't merely set the height percentage to the same thing as the width). Also, I would prefer to have a pure CSS solution, and not have to use `offsetWidth`, `clientWidth`, or other such properties in JavaScript.

Example:

```
<div style="width:45%;background-color:blue">My Content!</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible with pure CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this is not possible with pure CSS.

If you don't mind, let me offer a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) solution:

```
var $elem = ​$('div');
$(window).resize(function () {
    $elem.height($elem.width());
}).resize();
```

This will keep the height the same as the width even if the window size changes. You can try it out in the demo (try resizing):

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KReCT/)
- [jsFiddle Demo with a self-invoking function instead of calling `resize()`](http://jsfiddle.net/KReCT/1/)

I used jQuery because it helps a lot with the way browsers handle the width and height of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps someething like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gcvogxgL/

```css
p { background-color: red; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;}
p:before{content: ""; display: block; float: left; margin-top: 100%; }
p:after{ clear: both; content: ""; display: block; height: 1px;
margin-top: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

```html
<p>This is short</p>
<p>This is a medium</p>
<p>This is a very long square</p>
```

Comment: Sure.  All the magic happens in the p:before.  It's using margin-top: 100% which adds a margin that is the width of the element.  Percentages on margin-top are relative to the width of the element.  It floats it left so that the height of the text isn't accounted for (ignores it sort of), and then overflow:hidden on the main p tag makes the box grow to include all the elements (including the before pseudo element).

Comment: I don't remember why I put the p:after at all.  It might have been to work around a browser bug at the time, or maybe it was just something I was testing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with pure CSS. Using a tiny dollop of Javascript, it suddenly becomes very easy.

```
$("#mydiv").css("height", $("#mydiv").css("width"));​
```